# ¿limpiar o eliminar datos de json despues de consultar javascrip?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Hola llevo horas en esto y no logro hacerlo. Tengo un json

```
[{"id": 4,"nombres": "Juan"}, {"id": 5,"nombres": "Carlos"}]
```

uso ajax y al hacer click traigo los datos

```
$(".views").one("click", function () {
  let element = $(this)[0].parentElement.parentElement;
  let id = $(element).attr("task");
  $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "urlDatos",
    data: {
      id: id,
    },
    cache: false,
    success: function (result) {
      console.log(result);
      const resp = JSON.parse(result);
      for (x of resp) {
        var listaNombres = '<li class="lista-unidades">' + x.nombres + "</li>";
        $(".nombresCursos").append(listaNombres);
      }
    },
  });
});
```

El caso es que cada vez que hago click para consultar los datos del json se duplican es decir empieza con

- Juan
- Carlos

si hago click nuevamente pasa a

- Juan
- Carlos
- Juan
- Carlos

y si vuelvo hacer click

- Juan
- Carlos
- Juan
- Carlos
- Juan
- Carlos

Asi en un bucle sin fin, es por eso que quisiera saber si existe la manera de limpiar el json al hacer click nuevamente. Estoy horas y no eh encontrado mas que uso one.click para llamar a la funcion solo una vez, pero sigo con el problema.

Comment: Podrías hacer un empty antes de hacer los append..

Comment: no soy muy bueno con jquery no se si es asi          $(".nombresCursos").empty().append(listaNombres) aunque ahora solo me devuelve un elemento del json y no los 2

Comment: Podrías poner algo así  $(".nombresCursos").empty(); antes del for, para que luego el for haga los append pero siempre esté vacio antes de hacerlos.
Podrías tambien solo hacer los append en caso de que esté vacío, de esa forma solo lo haría una vez, sería wrappear el for..
Habría que entender bien que es lo que deseas hacer y como seguiría tras agregar a esas 2 personas.

Comment: no entiendo realmente como funciona, pero muchas gracias funciona para lo que quiero hacer. Tratare de investigar esto.

Comment: Dentro del for por cada objeto dentro del array estás haciendo un append, el append lo que hace es añadir al elemento .nombresCursos los resultados obtenidos, pero no se borran, están en el DOM.. Entonces cada vez que se agregan lo que hace es a lo que ya tiene añadir 2 más y así infinitamente.. El empty lo que hace es vaciar el elemento .nombresCursos y luego en el for se vuelve a agregar por los 2 append..